# How do I define multiple user types in Django using the existing User model?

Tags: python, django, django-users

Django has an awesome user model coupled with authentication. Using that, I want to define multiple user types, say a student and a professor. I want to do this using minimal change to the existing model.

One of the ways would be the User Groups. Another would be to extend the user model and store a flag. Which would be a better method for my problem, given that the two entities aren't entirely independent and a member of type one can also be a member of type two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand exactly your problem my choice would be an `OneToOneField`.

When I'm working on projects where the clients want customized users, one of the best solution is to create a new model with a `OneToOneField` pointing to the Django User like a `Profile` model. When you have an `User` object, you can do `user.profile` and you get the profile related with user (so you can do `user.profile.any_profile_field`).

I **recommend** you to use this kind of solution because it is easy to manage and scalable. If in 1 month you need to add a new property/field/value to an User, with this solution you only need to change this new model.

Here you can add to the Profile model as many fields as you need, and it's easy to manage because if you have the user you have the profile and viceversa

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('s', 'Student'),
        ('t', 'Teacher' ),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    type_user = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='s',choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

    #     ...    ...     ...
    #      Your fields here
```

---

EDIT

If you use this, your `authenticate` method can remain the same as it is right no.

You could do things as this example:

```
user = User.objects.all()[0]  # Get the first user

user.profile  # This would return the profile object
user.profile.type_user  # This would return the type_user of the profile related with this user
```

So you can use the profile fields in your login function, or when an user is accessing to some url, and check the type user to allow or not.

Example to control a template where only teachers can enter:

```
def teacher_view(request):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        # If user is not logged in, send it to login page
    else:
        if request.user.profile.type_user == 's':  # If the user is student
            # Here you can raise an error (not enough permissions), raise an error or redirect
```

Comment: I'm not very proficient with Django. Let's say I have this class. How do I use auth methods with it? Does `user` as an attribute follow all the methods?

Comment: The good thing is User model doesn't change. Following this example, if you have an User object, you can access to the profile of the User, and viceversa, if you have a Profile object you can access to the User

Comment: Ah! I just read up on `OneToOneField`. Thank you, this is awesome! *Why* do people use PHP?!

Comment: I learn Django before PHP, and when I saw the PHP file structure... OMG ! hahah Django powa!

Comment: One more thing. There are some attributes which are not common to the two user_types. How do I get unique fields?